# Exception at runtime which says: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getOutputContext()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/json/JsonWriteContext;

Tags: android, jackson, android-gradle-plugin, objectmapper, fasterxml

I've bumped into an Exception, which really doesn't appear to be informative about what really happened.

I guess this is maybe something due to some gradle dependencies.

To be specific Exception is this:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-8-thread-1 Process:app, PID: 28729 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getOutputContext()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/json/JsonWriteContext; in class Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/smile/SmileGenerator; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.smile.SmileGenerator' appears in /data/app/myapp.dev-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk) at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.smile.SmileGenerator.close(SmileGenerator.java:1537) at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:3898) at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:3147) at myapp.cache.BasicCache$2.run(BasicCache.java:190) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)

And my BasicCache is like this:

```
public class BasicCache<T> {

private static final int SCHEDULED_SAVING_DELAY_SECONDS = 30;

public enum CacheEncoding {
    NONE,
    BASE64,
    ENCRYPTED,
}

private CacheManager mCacheManager;
private final File mFile;

private final CacheEncoding mCacheEncoding;
private final boolean mSmileSerialization;

private final String mUser;

private T mData;

private Semaphore mSemaphore = new Semaphore(1, true);

private boolean mSaveScheduled;
private ScheduledExecutorService mScheduledExecutor;
private final Object mSchedulingMonitor = new Object();

public BasicCache(CacheManager cacheManager, String storageFilename, CacheEncoding cacheEncoding) {

    mCacheManager = cacheManager;
    mCacheEncoding = cacheEncoding;
    mSmileSerialization = false;

    mFile = new File(mCacheManager.getRootFolder(), storageFilename);

    mUser = null;
}

public BasicCache(CacheManager cacheManager, String user, String storageFilename, CacheEncoding cacheEncoding) {
    this(cacheManager, user, storageFilename, cacheEncoding, false);
}

public BasicCache(CacheManager cacheManager, String user, String storageFilename, CacheEncoding cacheEncoding, boolean smileSerialziation) {
    mCacheManager = cacheManager;
    mCacheEncoding = cacheEncoding;
    mSmileSerialization = smileSerialziation;

    mUser = user;

    File userFolder = new File(mCacheManager.getRootFolder(), mCacheManager.getUsersFolderName(user));
    userFolder.mkdirs();
    mFile = new File(userFolder, storageFilename);
}

protected T initData() {
    try {
        //noinspection unchecked
        return (T) (getDataJavaType().getRawClass().newInstance());

    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        return null;
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        return null;
    }
}

private JavaType getDataJavaType() {
    Type parentType = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    Type t = ((ParameterizedType) parentType).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    return mCacheManager.getController().getJsonMapper().constructType(t);
}

public T getAndLock() {
    lock();
    return getInternal();
}

public T getUnlocked() {
    if (mData != null)
        return mData;

    try {
        lock();
        return getInternal();
    } finally {
        unlock();
    }
}

private T getInternal() {
    if (mData != null)
        return mData;

    mData = loadFromDisk();

    if (mData == null) {
        mData = initData();
        return mData;
    } else
        return mData;
}

public void setAndUnlock(T data) {
    mData = data;
    unlock();
}

private void lock() {
    try {
        mSemaphore.acquire();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        unlock();
    }
}

public void unlock() {
    mSemaphore.release();
}

public void scheduleSave() {
    synchronized (mSchedulingMonitor) {
        if (!mSaveScheduled) {

            if (mScheduledExecutor == null)
                mScheduledExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

            mScheduledExecutor.schedule(new Runnable() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {
                                                synchronized (mSchedulingMonitor) {
                                                    mSaveScheduled = false;
                                                    save();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                    SCHEDULED_SAVING_DELAY_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            mSaveScheduled = true;
        }
    }
}

public void save() {

    lock();

    getCacheManager().getController().getCacheSavingExecutor().execute(new Runnable() {

        @SuppressLint("TrulyRandom")
        @Override
        public void run() {

            if (mData != null) {

                try {
                    if (mCacheEncoding == CacheEncoding.ENCRYPTED) {
                        String secure = Settings.Secure.getString(
                                mCacheManager.getController().getContext().getContentResolver(),
                                Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
                        getObjectMapper().writeValue(EncryptionUtils.encrypt(new FileOutputStream(mFile), secure), mData);
                    } else if (mCacheEncoding == CacheEncoding.BASE64)
                        getObjectMapper().writeValue(new Base64OutputStream(new FileOutputStream(mFile), Base64.DEFAULT), mData);
                    else
                        getObjectMapper().writeValue(mFile, mData);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            unlock();
        }

    });

}

private T loadFromDisk() {

    try {
        if (mCacheEncoding == CacheEncoding.ENCRYPTED) {
            String secure = Settings.Secure.getString(
                    mCacheManager.getController().getContext().getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
            mData = getObjectMapper().readValue(EncryptionUtils.decrypt(new FileInputStream(mFile), secure), getDataJavaType());
        } else if (mCacheEncoding == CacheEncoding.BASE64)
            mData = getObjectMapper().readValue(new Base64InputStream(new FileInputStream(mFile), Base64.DEFAULT), getDataJavaType());
        else
            mData = getObjectMapper().readValue(mFile, getDataJavaType());
        return mData;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }

}

private ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
    if (mSmileSerialization)
        return mCacheManager.getController().getSmileMapper();
    else
        return mCacheManager.getController().getJsonMapper();
}

public boolean isValidUser(String user) {
    return TextUtils.equals(user, mUser);
}

protected CacheManager getCacheManager() {
    return mCacheManager;
}

protected String getUser() {
    return mUser;
  }

}
```

So the error points to this line in my 'save' method in BasicCache:

```
getObjectMapper().writeValue(mFile, mData);
```

Here, also my dependencies in gradle:

```
ext.daggerVersion = '2.11'
ext.roomVersion = '1.0.0-alpha9'
ext.lifecycleVersion = '1.0.0-alpha9'
ext.supportLibraryVersion = '27.0.1'
ext.jacksonVersion = '2.5.1'
ext.icePickVersion = '3.2.0'
ext.fragmentArgsVersion = '3.0.2'
ext.dartVersion = '2.0.2'
ext.hensonVersion = '2.0.2'
ext.parcelerVersion = '1.1.9'
ext.retrofitVersion = '2.2.0'
ext.okHttpVersion = '3.6.0'

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

// Tests
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

// Multidex
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'

// Kotlin
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"

// Support libraries
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportLibraryVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"

implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.6'

compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.6'

// Jackson
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:$jacksonVersion"
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:$jacksonVersion"
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:$jacksonVersion"
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-smile:$jacksonVersion"

// Butterknife
compile "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$butterKnifeVersion"
annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$butterKnifeVersion"

// Room
compile "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$roomVersion"
compile "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:$roomVersion"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$roomVersion"

// Lifecycle
compile "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:$lifecycleVersion"
compile "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifecycleVersion"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$lifecycleVersion"

// Dagger
compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVersion"
compile "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$daggerVersion"
compile "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$daggerVersion"
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$daggerVersion"

compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'

compile ('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1') {
    exclude module: 'stax'
    exclude module: 'stax-api'
    exclude module: 'xpp3'
}

// Parceler
compile "org.parceler:parceler-api:$parcelerVersion"
annotationProcessor "org.parceler:parceler:$parcelerVersion"

// Fragment args
compile "com.hannesdorfmann.fragmentargs:annotation:$fragmentArgsVersion"
compile "com.hannesdorfmann.fragmentargs:bundler-parceler:$fragmentArgsVersion"
annotationProcessor "com.hannesdorfmann.fragmentargs:processor:$fragmentArgsVersion"

// Okhttp
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okHttpVersion"
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okHttpVersion"

// IcePick
compile "frankiesardo:icepick:$icePickVersion"
annotationProcessor "frankiesardo:icepick-processor:$icePickVersion"

// RxJava
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'

// Retrofit
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:$retrofitVersion"

// Dart
compile "com.f2prateek.dart:dart:$dartVersion"
annotationProcessor "com.f2prateek.dart:dart-processor:$dartVersion"

// Henson
compile "com.f2prateek.dart:henson:$hensonVersion"
annotationProcessor "com.f2prateek.dart:henson-processor:$hensonVersion"

compile 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.9'
compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'

compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
compile('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.8@aar') {
    transitive = true
}

provided "com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.4.1"
annotationProcessor "com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.4.1"

provided fileTree(include: ['com.symbol.emdk.jar'], dir: '..\\emdk\\libs')
compile fileTree(exclude: ['com.symbol.emdk.jar'], dir: 'libs')

dependencies {
    compile project(":nexo")
}

compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.0.1'
}
```

**UPDATE:**
It appears, that when i changed my jacksonVersion to 2.9.3 the problem is not occuring. But I'm not sure about it.

Comment: did you try clean build?

Comment: @GautamChibde yes, of course

Answer (score 0):

In order to make jackson-module-kotlin work on Android < API 24 you must stay on version 2.9.6.

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin/issues/176

As Moshi can also generate adapters for you and not require the use of the reflect library, it is a better choice in most cases for Android dev.